# Clarify how docker command COPY behaves relative to docker build context

Tags: docker

I want to copy the contents of a parent directory (relative to the position of the Dockerfile) into my image.

This is the folder structure:

```
app-root/
  docker/
    php81aws/
      some-folder
      Dockerfile
      start-container
      supervisord.conf
  app_folders
  app_files
```

I'm calling docker build as follows:

```
app-root#> docker build -t laravel -f docker/php81aws/Dockerfile .
```

Or from `docker compose` with:

```
services: 
  laravel:
     build:
       context: ./
       dockerfile: docker/php81aws/Dockerfile
```

Therefore, the context should be in the app-root directory.
In the dockerfile, I'm using COPY like so:

```
COPY docker/php81aws/start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY docker/php81aws/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www/
```

It always gives me this error:

```
failed to compute cache key: "/start-container" not found: not found
```

I tried to use `COPY ./docker/php81aws/start-container` and `COPY start-container` but the error is always the same. Of course copying the parent directory also fails.

Comment: That structure looks like it should work (I might move the Dockerfile up to the repository root to avoid the `docker build -f` option).  Do you have a `.dockerignore` file that's causing files to be excluded from the build context?

Comment: wow. That was it... I was excluding the docker folder. I didn't think it meant excluding it from the context!

Comment: if you put this in an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in a comment that your top-level `app-root` directory has a `.dockerignore` file that excludes the entire `docker` directory.  While the Dockerfile will still be available, nothing else in that tree can be `COPY`ed into the image, and if you `COPY ./ ./` to copy the entire build context into the image, that directory won't be present.

Deleting this line from the `.dockerignore` file should fix your issue.

In general you want the `.dockerignore` file to include anything that's part of your host build-and-test environment, but should not by default be included in an image, possibly because the Dockerfile is going to rebuild it.  In a Node context, for example, you almost always want to exclude the host's `node_modules` directory, or in a Java context often the Gradle `build` or Maven `target` directories.  Anything you do want to include in the image needs to not be listed in `.dockerignore`.